# No overload match this call (Component React + Typescript)

Tags: typescript, react-native

In my placeholderTextColor the error of the title persist and do not find a solution

```
 import React from 'react';
import { TextInputProps } from 'react-native';
import { color } from 'react-native-reanimated';

import { Container, TextInput, Icon } from './styles';

interface InputProps extends TextInputProps {
  name: string;
  icon: string;
}
// todas as propriedades "rest" sao passadas para o TExt Input, no caso apenas o placeholder
const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ name, icon, ...placeholder }) => (
  <Container>
    <Icon name={icon} size={20} color="#666360" />

    <TextInput
      keyboardAppearance="dark"
      placeholderTextColor="#666360"
      {...placeholder}
    />
  </Container>
);
export default Input;
```

The error persists, if I remove spread operator the error is vanish, but it s not a solution

Full Error

(JSX attribute) placeholderTextColor?: string | typeof OpaqueColorValue | undefined
The text color of the placeholder string

No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<TextInputProps & RefAttributes, "ref" | "style" | "hitSlop" | "onLayout" | "pointerEvents" | "removeClippedSubviews" | ... 104 more ... | "showSoftInputOnFocus"> & Partial<...>, "ref" | ... 109 more ... | "showSoftInputOnFocus"> & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
Type 'ColorValue' is not assignable to type 'string | unique symbol | undefined'.
Type 'unique symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | unique symbol | undefined'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<typeof TextInput, DefaultTheme, {}, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<typeof TextInput, DefaultTheme, {}, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error.
Type 'ColorValue' is not assignable to type 'string | unique symbol | undefined'.
Type 'unique symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | unique symbol | undefined'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(1626, 5): The expected type comes from property 'placeholderTextColor' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<TextInputProps & RefAttributes, "ref" | "style" | "hitSlop" | ... 107 more ... | "showSoftInputOnFocus"> & Partial<...>, "ref" | ... 109 more ... | "showSoftInputOnFocus"> & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'
index.d.ts(1626, 5): The expected type comes from property 'placeholderTextColor' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<TextInputProps & RefAttributes, "ref" | "style" | "hitSlop" | ... 107 more ... | "showSoftInputOnFocus"> & Partial<...>, "ref" | ... 109 more ... | "showSoftInputOnFocus"> & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'

Comment: what is inside placeholder? in your interface you only have name, icon and placeholderTextColor, you cannot accept other props

Comment: Inside the placeholder is just the placeholder from a input. I put the placeholderTextColor in the interface, but is not the correct thing to do, the correct code is without him, but the same error (overload match) shows in placeholderTextColor

}

Comment: that placeholder contains what props? can u add it to the interface?

Comment: For now, receive  <Input name="email" icon="mail" placeholder="Email" />

 <Input name="password" icon="lock" placeholder="Senha" />, so, just receive the prop placeholder with word Email and Senha

Comment: I do this, but the placeHolderColor show other error (JSX attribute) placeholderTextColor?: string | typeof OpaqueColorValue | undefined
The text color of the placeholder string. No overload matches this call. The app work, but VSCode show the error

Comment: I didn't get any error in https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-ptolemy-lgr6h?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Interesting, but the difference is that my TextInput is a styled-component

Comment: I will post in my Github and to clarify the ideas

Comment: and full error code would be nice, we may have been climbing up the wrong tree.

Comment: My Repository https://github.com/nicktecno/BarbeariaMobile.git

Comment: I post the full error in the post

Comment: placeholderTextColor is the default text input props, with the assignment of type color. You changed it to string, which may be the cause of the problem. try my answer

Answer (score 2):

You are using placeholderTextColor which is a existing prop of TextInput but you are reassigning it as string.

can u try or deleting it.

```
interface InputProps extends TextInputProps {
  name: string;
  icon: string;
  placeholderTextColor: color;
}
```

Comment: The error is gone...but show another error inside of the text input with the same message in the main post

Comment: In My Github this change was maded 
 github.com/nicktecno/BarbeariaMobile.git

Comment: I haven't used styled-component so I'm not sure whether styled components is passing any weird props over. Try importing textinput from react-native and see whether we can isolate the problem to styled-components?

Comment: Worked, I think that find the solution of the problem, The Styled Components

Comment: maybe instead of finding a solution, to use other way to style the text input.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this case it was receive the property imported inner other property placeholder like below:

```
interface InputProps extends TextInputProps {
  name: string;
  icon: string;
  placeholder: string;
}
// todas as propriedades "rest" sao passadas para o TExt Input, no caso apenas o placeholder
const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ name, icon, placeholder }) => (
  <Container>
    <Icon name={icon} size={20} color="#666360" />
    <TextInput keyboardAppearance="dark" placeholder={placeholder} />
  </Container>
);
export default Input;
```

Thx  @Someone Special to find the problem with Styled Components